# Mixin parameter as a part of the class name

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

Hi is it possible to use mixin parameter as a part of the class name used in this mixin or do it in some other way?

```
.thumbs-mixin(@length) {

    &.thumbs-@length {

        .slick-track {
            width: 180px * @length - 20px;
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0px, 0px);
            left: 50%;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Curly braces around the variable ie. `&.thumbs-@{length}`

```
.thumbs-mixin(@length) {

  &.thumbs-@{length} {
    .slick-track {
      width: 180px * @length - 20px;
      transform: translate3d(-50%, 0px, 0px);
      left: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

More info: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation